# One to many mapping and additional condition column not part of a foreign key

Tags: nhibernate, orm, nhibernate-mapping

I'm trying to solve problem with XML mapping. 
I've got two views base one some tables.

```
Training
- Id int PK
- LanguageId int

Module
 - Id PK
 - TrainingId FK
 - LanguageId int
```

In both views has set key to id.

I would like to construct one to many mapping in Training class with foreign key TrainingId including column which is not a part of a primary key - LanguageId. This is part of xml which I have now.

```
    <bag name="Modules" inverse="true" cascade="none">
  <key>
    <column name="TrainingId"/>
  </key>
  <one-to-many class="Model.Domain.ModuleCategoryTranslationView" />
</bag>
```

I would like to include somehow condition where Training.LanguageId = Module.LanguageId.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

This actually doesn't make any sense.

If Training ID is the PK, it is unique right? So how can you create one Training with the same ID for multiple Languages anyways?

Meaning if Training ID is unique already, why do you need to add LanguageID to the condition of the Bag?

If you want to have Training.Id + Training.LanguageID to be the Primary Key, you should map that as a composite Key and use it within the bag, this should work.

And no, what you are asking for is not supported as far as I know, the only way would be to define a filter and apply it at runtime to your queries.